# Scoping issues when rendering transcluded content with <content>

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to make a simple component to display a loading screen until data has arrived and provide simple error handling:

```html
<loading done="ctrl.dataLoaded" error="ctrl.dataError">
  <graph
      width="ctrl.graphWidth"
      data="ctrl.data">
  </graph>
</loading>
```

The template for `<loading>` looks like this:

```html
<div ng-switch="cmp.error">
  <div ng-switch-when="null">
    <div ng-switch="cmp.done">
      <div ng-switch-when="false">
        <h1>Loading, please wait...</h1>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <content></content>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
  <h1>An Error occurred: {{cmp.error}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the transcluded `<graph>` component only sees null on its attributes instead of the expected data from the controller, thus failing to render.

I assume this is because it's rendered in the scope of `<loading>`, where the original `ctrl` binding is not available anymore? Is there a way around this, preserving the original attribute bindings?

edit: As mentioned in the comment below, the problem seems to come from the combination of transclusion with `<content>` and having a component that receives data over its attributes. Just transcluding simple values like `{{ctrl.graphWidth}}` works fine.

edit2: As requested, controller

```dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[some-graph]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl')
class SomeGraphController implements NgAttachAware {
  bool dataLoaded = false;
  String dataError = null;
  int graphWidth = -1;
  List<Point> data;

  void attach() {
    requestData().then((d) {
      data = d;
      dataLoaded = true;
    }).catchError((e) => dataError = e.toString());
  }
}
```

and chart component

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'graph',
    template: "<svg id='chart'></svg>",
    cssUrl: '/graph.css',
    publishAs: 'cmp')
class GraphComponent implements NgShadowRootAware {
  @NgOneWay('width')
  int width;

  @NgOneWay('data')
  List<Point> data;

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    print('displaying $data');
    drawGraph(shadowRoot.querySelector("#chart"));
  }
}
```

The print statement prints 'displaying null' when the graph component is used within the loading component, but correctly prints the data assigned from the controller when used outside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a scoping issue.
I tried to reproduce without all those ng-switch tags and graph got the value from the controller that was applied to a ancestor of `<loading>`.

Comment: Hm, when I replace <graph> by eg {{ctrl.graphWidth}} the value does show up correctly. However, when I use <graph> outside of the loading component it works correctly, so the problem seems to come from the combination of the two. Which is why it made me think of scoping. (I assume {{ctrl.graphWidth}} gets evaluated right away, whereas <graph ...> gets evaluated only after being inserted in <loading>)

Comment: Can you please add the code of your controller and the graph component?

Comment: Can you change `width` and `data` to getters/setters in GraphComponent and print the value when the setter gets called? It could be a timing issue. There were several reports the last weeks that attribute values are not yet set when `onShadowRoot` is called. A workaround would be to wrap the the code inside `onShadowRoot` in a new `Future(() { print('... });`

Comment: According to the prints I added, the setters are called with 'null'.
Wrapping everything in a Future did not help, even when the future is executed the values from the attributes are still null.

Comment: Ok, if the setters are only called with null, the future can't help. Have you tried without the switch directives. Maybe they interfere in some way?

Comment: What Dart/Angular version are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is actually opposite from what I thought: The graph is rendered right away before being passed to loading. At this point, data isn't yet present, which is why the attributes are set to null and drawing fails. If I instead redraw whenever a non-null data attribute is set everything works fine. In practice it's a bit more difficult, because I have more than one data attribute, I'll have to figure out some solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in

```
<loading done="ctrl.dataLoaded" error="ctrl.dataError">
  <graph
      width="ctrl.graphWidth"
      data="ctrl.data">
  </graph>
</loading>
```

`<graph>` is rendered right away, before being passed to `<loading>`. At this point, the data isn't yet present (that's the point of having the loading element), so graph gets null in its attributes and fails to render. Later, when the data has finished loading and the `<loading>` component changes what it displays doesn't render again, the result of the failed first rendering is shown.

Possible solutions

- Render whenever all required attributes are set to non-null values
- Have a special `data-present` attribute and only render when that is set to true

Both of these kind of defeat the purpose of having a `<loading>` tag, not yet sure what I'll do. The perfect solution would be lazy evaluation, not sure if AngularDart can do that?